# Screen flickering in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, graphics, screen, flicker

My screen is continuously flickering while running on Ubuntu 18.04.

```
$ sudo lshw -c display
[sudo] password for suchith: 
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 5500
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:53 memory:a8000000-a8ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display
       description: 3D controller
       product: GK208BM [GeForce 920M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:56 memory:a9000000-a9ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:aa000000-aa07ffff
```

```
$ uname -a
Linux redshellspy 4.19.0-041900-generic #201810221809 SMP Mon Oct 22 22:11:45 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: With which graphics does it happen?

Comment: I don't know how to see graphics specs. Can you tell me how to do that.

Comment: You have two graphics cards. You complain of screen flickering. I'm asking which card is in use when it happens? Or is it with both Intel or Nvidia? And which drivers version have you installed for the Nvidia?

Comment: My Nvidia driver version is 390.116 (got it using Nvidia-smi).  The flickering is happening when I use the intel graphic card. (checked with lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA" )

Comment: Please [edit] and add that information to que question itself. Now, if the flickering happens only with Intel I'm not sure what to suggest.